# Displaying dynamic form on click of a button in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Am new to angularjs i want to display a dynamic form fields that must have unique name so that it will help me for validation..

Thanks in advance..

below is Script code

```
$scope.contact = [
{
  cp: '',
  disgn: '',
  dept: '',
  email: '',
  mob: '',
  wta: '',
  landline1: '',
  ext: '',
  landline2: '',
  ext: ''
}];

$scope.add = function() {
    var dataObj = {cp:'', disgn:'',dept:'',email:'',mob:'',wta:'',landline1:'',ext:'',landline2:'',ext:''};
    $scope.contact.push(dataObj);
}
```

below is HTML code

```
        <div ng-repeat="input in contact">
        <br><br>
          <div class="form-group col-md-8">
            CONTACT PERSON
            <input type="text" name="input.cp" class="form-control" ng-model="input.cp"/>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-8">
            DESIGNATION
            <input type="text" name="input.disgn" class="form-control" ng-model="input.disgn"/>
          </div> 

          <div class="form-group col-md-8">
            DEPARTMENT
            <input type="text" name="input.dept" class="form-control" ng-model="input.dept"/>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-8">
            Email*:
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="input.email" required />
            <span style="color:red" ng-show="form.email.$dirty && form.email.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="form.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
            <span ng-show="form.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
            </span>
          </div> 

          <div class="form-group col-md-8">
            MOBILE
            <input type="number" name="input.mob" class="form-control" ng-model="input.mob"/>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-8">
            WHATSAPP#
            <input type="number" name="input.wta" class="form-control" ng-model="input.wta"/>
          </div> 
          <div class="form-group col-md-8">
            LANDLINE1 
            <input type="number" name="input.landline1" class="form-control" ng-model="input.landline1"/>
          </div>   
          <div class="form-group col-md-8">
            EXT:
            <input type="text" name="input.ext" class="form-control" ng-model="input.ext"/>
          </div>  
          <div class="form-group col-md-8">
            LANDLINE2 
            <input type="number" name="input.landline2" class="form-control" ng-model="input.landline2"/>
          </div>   
          <div class="form-group col-md-8">
            EXT:
            <input type="text" name="input.ext" class="form-control" ng-model="input.ext"/>
          </div>                

        </div>
        <button ng-click="add()">Add Contact Person</button>
```

If i add new contact person since the email name for old and new email inputs are validation is not working

Comment: Please clarify your question by showing the code.

Comment: where is the code???

Comment: share whatever you tried, so we ll help you.

Comment: i shared the code .. in the above code validation is happening for all new email input fields..

Comment: why you are using `input.disgn` it should be `contact.desgn`

Answer (score 0):

If you have `$scope.contact` object:-

```
$scope.contact = {
    cp: '',
    disgn: '',
    dept: '',
    email: '',
    mob: '',
    wta: '',
    landline1: '',
    ext: '',
    landline2: '',
    ext: ''
};
```

Then declare HTML like:-

```
<div class="form-group col-md-8">
    DESIGNATION
    <input type="text" name="disgn" class="form-control" ng-model="contact.disgn"/>
</div>
```